# Rendering a component in order/after one has rendered (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an app that displays data from an API and a button for loading more.

The problem I have is that the button flashes on the screen before the data list is fetched and displayed.

I want the button to display only at the bottom of the page after the list.

What is a way I can do this?

The code :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetchTopRatedMovies(pageNumber).then((newData) =>
      setApiData({
        ...newData,
        results: [...apiData.results, ...newData.results]
      })
    );
    setLoading(false);

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [pageNumber]);

  return (
    <div className='top-rated-page-wrapper'>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <MovieList results={results} />
          <PageButton pageLimit={pageLimit} loadMore={loadMore} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
```

To clarify. 
The button loads first and flashes before the data is rendered. 
The button is then in the position where I want it at the bottom of the page. 
I don't want to button to be visible until the data has been rendered.

Comment: You can position: fixed your button by css or else you can hide it until the data has been fetched by keeping a state variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional render to render load more button when `data > 0`

```
{ apiData ? <PageButton pageLimit={pageLimit} loadMore={loadMore} /> : null }
```

Comment: Thanks I had to alter slightly and do apiData > 0.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this article will answer your question. The author uses the same hook and speaks specifically how to manage the lifecycle event with a state variable.

https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-hook-examples/